# How to change DisplayType of List item shape in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, shapes

I have a content `MyContainer` which has a ​`Container` part attached to it.

Then i have several `MyContainerItem` contents which have a `Containable` part attached to it and these are assigned to `MyContainer`.

Now, if the content `MyContainer` is rendered, it internally uses the List shape and therefore each `MyContainerItem` content is rendered with the `Summary` display type, which seems hard-coded in Orchard.

Is there any way to change the display type of `MyContainerItem` to `Detail` without altering the core code?

I tried the shape shifting technique in my alternates but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue before on other content parts (don't remember which), but what you could do is take the following steps:

1 Create a custom part and record to attach to the content types that have the ContainerPart:

```
public CustomContainerPart : ContentPart<CustomContainerPartRecord> {
    public string DisplayType {
        // property setter and getter
    }
}
```

2 Create a handler that attaches the CustomContainerPart on the content types that have the ContainerPart:

```
public class CustomContainerPartHandler : ContentHandler {
    private readonly IContentDefinitionManager _contentDefinitionManager;

    public CustomContainerPartHandler(IContentDefinitionManager contentDefinitionManager) {
        _contentDefinitionManager = contentDefinitionManager;
    }

    protected override void Activating(ActivatingContentContext context) {
        base.Activating(context);

        // weld the CustomContainerPart dynamically, if the type has the ContainerPart
        var contentTypeDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetTypeDefinition(context.ContentType);
        if (contentTypeDefinition == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (contentTypeDefinition.Parts.Any(part => part.PartDefinition.Name == typeof(ContainerPart).Name)) {
            context.Builder.Weld<CustomContainerPart>();
        }
    }
}
```

3 Create the driver for the custom part and use this Display method:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(CustomContainerPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {    
    return ContentShape("Parts_Container_CustomContained", () => {
        var containerPart = part.As<ContainerPart>();
        // copy code from Orchard.Core/Containers/Drivers/ContainerPartDriver.cs here and tweak it to use the CustomContainerPart display type property
        // ..
        var listShape = shapeHelper.List();
        listShape.AddRange(pageOfItems.Select(item => _contentManager.BuildDisplay(item, part.DisplayType))); // here use your custom part setting
        // ..
    });
}
```

4 And finally your Placement.info:

```
<Place Parts_Container_Contained="-" />
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
  <Place Parts_Container_CustomContained="Content:7.5"/>
</Match>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but a bit too complicated, see my answer how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i was approaching it the wrong way.

It came to my mind that alternates would be the better solution as it doesn't alter the list behavior.

Now i understand it this way: list should normally show a summary of each item and when i click on the item the details are shown, makes sense.

So instead of changing the `DisplayType` just create an alternate with the appropriate name according to the docs:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes#NamingShapesandTemplates

In my case the alternate would be `Content.Summary-MyContainerItem.cshtml` with the following content:

```
@Model.Content.Items[0].Html
```

Comment: You can indeed do this, but then you don't actually use the detail display type, you just tweak your summary display type to do the same. This means that if you alter the content type, it won't automatically reflect in your summary view (because it isn't the detail view).

Comment: That said, if your requirements are simply to display it in a custom way (not per se the Detail display type), this would be the best option :D

Comment: @devqon Yes absolutely, i accepted your answer as it's the solution to what i was initially trying to do. I will surely come to it later on.